# Get a custom HTML tag inside a PHP variable

Tags: php, html

Here is what I want to accomplish.

I have many pages with products tests, and I need to create a price comparison for the specific product of this page. To do that, I have to identify the product of the page to query my database.

I thought the best way was to create a custom HTML tag with the name of the product and search for it in the page to put it in a PHP variable.

If this is the good way to do it, how can I achieve this? I'm not a PHP developer and I saw something about `DOMelement` and some code which looks like exactly what I need to do.

```
<?php
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
 <book>Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture</book>
 <book>Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Software Design</book>
 <book>Clean Code</book>
</books>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

This is for XML but it should work for HTML as well. The only thing is, how can I parse the current HTML page with this `DOMelement`?

Is this the way to do it? If so, how would you do it?

EDIT :

Sorry if it was not clear, but I understand what ArtisiticPhoenix is saying and this is why my approach will probably not work.

What I have is an HTML page with a review of a product, I want to add a price comparison for this product at the bottom of the article. My database is already setup with prices from different shops. Here is the code I wrote to get the values from my database:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select   p.Nom_produit, 
                                       b.Nom_boutique,
                                       b.logo_boutique,
                                       pp.Prix_produit, 
                                       pp.Prix_livraion,
                                       pp.Prix_produit + pp.Prix_livraion as Prix_total,
                                       pp.url_produit
                                from   Boutiques b
                                       Prix_produit pp
                                       Produits p
                               where   P.id_produit = pp.id_produit
                                 and   b.id_boutique = pp.id_boutique
                                 and   p.Nom_Produit = '.$NOM_PROD'
                              HAVING   pp.date_maj = max(date_maj)
                              order by Prix_produit+Prix_livraison asc LIMIT 5");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $table_resultats .= "
    $table_resultats .= "<table>"
    $table_resultats .= "<tr>"
    $table_resultats .= "<th>Logo</th>"
    $table_resultats .= "<th>Nom boutique</th>"
    $table_resultats .= "<th>Nom Produit</th>"
    $table_resultats .= "<th>Prix Produit</th>"
    $table_resultats .= "<th>Prix Livraison</th>"
    $table_resultats .= "<th>Prix Total</th>"
    $table_resultats .= "<th>Acheter</th>"
    $table_resultats .= "</tr>"

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $table_resultats .= "<tr>"
        $table_resultats .= "<td>" . $row["logo_boutique"]. "</td>"
        $table_resultats .= "<td>" . $row["Nom_boutique"]. "</td>"
        $table_resultats .= "<td>" . $row["Nom_produit"]. "</td>"
        $table_resultats .= "<td>" . $row["Prix_Produit"]. "</td>"
        $table_resultats .= "<td>" . $row["Prix_livraison"]. "</td>"
        $table_resultats .= "<td>" . $row["Prix_total"]. "</td>"
        $table_resultats .= '<td><form action="'. $row["url_produit"]. '"><input type="button" value="Acheter"></form></td>'
        $table_resultats .= "</tr>"
    }
    $table_resultats .= "</table>"
} else {
    echo "Pas de résultats";
}
echo $table_resultats
$conn->close();
?>
```

My main problem is how to set the variable `$NOM_PROD` in my query. I have to make a link between the product and my article, and I'm looking for a way to create this link.

Comment: Not to answer if the approach is correct. But DomDocument has a function called `loadHTML()`. So yes it works for HTML as well.

Comment: The approach is not correct, not unless this is not your HTML that is.  If it is your HTML then generate the page and do the comparison when that is done, otherwise how will you get php to check the html at all.  Basically where does this html with the custom tag come from.

Comment: This is a very broad question with many answer being correct. Your approach could certainly work, but could maybe also be replaced with a more efficient method if applicable. Provide us with context of your situation. What kind of data do you handle and on which way is it generated. Edit this information into your question and narrow it down.

Comment: If you want to identify your product, why don't you just include something like `<input type="hidden" name="itemcode" value="someitemcode" />` and search for that? Why do you need to go into creating a custom html tag?

Comment: Thank you for you help Koljanep, because I didn't know I can use that :) can you please elaborate about the methods you'll use to search for the value of this input ?